# how pylons decorator works

Tags: python, pylons

```
from decorator import decorator
from pylons.decorators.util import get_pylons

def allowed_roles(roles):
    def wrapper(func, *args, **kwargs):
        session = get_pylons(args).session
        # edit pylons session here.
        return func(*args, **kwargs)
    return decorator(wrapper)
```

Can anyone explain how it works?

Comment: That looks odd to me - don't really understand why `session` is defined but never referenced. Probably missing something stupid though.

Comment: The argument to allowed_roles, `roles`, is also not used. ?

Answer (score 2):

Like any other decorator works -

A decorator is a function which receives a function as an argument, and returns another function. 
The returned function will "take the place" from the original function.

Since the desired effect with a decoratos is usually to be able to run some code before and after the original function (the one being decorated) runs, decorators create a new function which takes any number of anonymous and named parameters (the * prefixing "args"  and the ** prefixing "kwargs" are responsible to store the parameters in a list and a dictionary, respectively)

Inside this new function, you have a place to write your verification code - and then it calls the original function - which in this context is called "func", and returns its original value.

the "decorator.decorator" call is not strictly needed: it jsut modifies some ttrbitues of the wrapper function so that it appears more closely to be the original funciton (like the 'func_name' attribute) - but the code should work without it.

After definning a decorator, you have to apply it to a function or method you wish to decorate: just put an @allowed_roles  in a line prefixing the function definition you want to decorate.

Comment: (in time: this is not specifc to pylons - this way of decorating functions or methods is a Python feature